# Returning a number and incrementing a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, increment

**Problem:**

Incrementing a variable based on a returned number from a function

The function randomNumber(i) will return the number 1, 2 or 3.

**JS code:**

```
var i, counter, aNum, bNum, cNum = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) 
{
    var counter = randomNumber(i);

    if (counter == '1') {
        aNum++;
    }
    else if (counter == '2') {
        bNum++;
    }
    else if (counter == '3') {
        cNum++;
    }
}
```

**Desired solution:**

To allow aNum, bNum, and cNum to increment in value. When I write out an alert(), it only gives me NaN for the different aNum-cNum. What am I missing?

Comment: You never show them being defined. What is their initial value?

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry about that, left that code out.

Comment: Declare like this  `var i, counter, aNum = bNum = cNum = 0;`

Comment: @hbk35 that won't do what you think it will do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialise your variables.

```
var aNum = 0, bNum = 0, cNum = 0, counter = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) 
{
    counter = randomNumber(i);

    if (counter == '1') {
        aNum++;
    }
    else if (counter == '2') {
        bNum++;
    }
    else if (counter == '3') {
        cNum++;
    }
}
```